# Prove that $\lnot[\exists x\;A(x)]$ is equivalent to ${\forall}x\;[{\lnot} A(x)]$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

### Question

Is this a good proof?

### Statement

$\lnot[\exists x A(x)]$ is equivalent to ${\forall}x[{\lnot} A(x)]$

### Proof

I'm proving an equivalence, so I'm going to prove an implication from left to right and then from right to left.

#### Left to right

Assume $\lnot[\exists x A(x)]$. If it's not the case that there's at least one $x$ for which $A(x)$ is true. Then all $x$'s fail to satisfy $A(x)$. So for all $x$'s $A(x)$ is false. In symbols $\forall x [\lnot A(x)]$.

#### Right to left

$\forall x [\lnot A(x)]$. If for all $x$'s, $\lnot A(x)$ is true. Then there is no $x$ for which $A(x)$ is true. Then it's not the case that there is an $x$ for which $A(x)$ is true. In symbols $\lnot[\exists x A(x)]$.

Comment: [Pdf p.132-134 of forallx by Magnus, Barton, et al.](https://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc-solutions.pdf) contains Fitch-style natural-deduction proofs of these results. Your informal reasoning is fine, although I would expand each direction by one or two more lines to make it clearer that I'm not merely restating/translating the symbolic sentences in/to English.